# Liquibase Update - Output SQL - Oracle Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, output, liquibase

We have our stored procedures managed in code as Liquibase change log files (one change set/stored proc per file).  These are marked to run every time we deploy.  The format of the stored procedure SQL is as follows:

```
<createProcedure ...>
  <![CDATA[
    CREATE OR REPLACE MyStoredProc...
      ...
    END;
  ]]>
</createProcedure>
```

When we run these change logs against a database everything works fine.  However, when we use the updateSQL command to generate a SQL script from the change logs, Liquibase does NOT include the "/" batch separator at the end of each create or replace procedure block.

When I try adding the "/" to the stored proc code in Liquibase, it follows the create or replace statement and the "/" with another semi-colon (;).  Either way, you cannot execute the batch script that Liquibase generates because these two issues generate errors.

If anyone has encountered this issue and has some guidance, please post here.  This is a show-stopper for our implementation because some of our customers will not allow Liquibase to execute the change logs directly against their production instances.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention, we have a "master" change log that includes each individual stored proc change log file, so we can execute one change log and they are all executed.

Comment: There have been some related fixes in Liquibase 3.3.3. Can you try the newer version?